# Programmatically Create Windows Credential Manager Entries

Tags: windows, powershell, credentials, credential-manager

I want to create (not backup/restore, for a variety of reasons) Windows Credential Manager entries, for example Samba Share credentials, but others as well.

I do not want to set up PCs manually for this.

Is there a way to create the credentials programmatically?  Specifically, I need them to actually show up in the Windows Credential Manager.

I've tried using `New-StoredCredential` in Powershell and `Get-StoredCredential` and while they both work, they aren't actually showing up in my credential manager (could this be security settig related?)

I am not opposed to doing this via Python outside of Powershell if there is a good library for it that my Googling has been unable to find.

Thanks.

Comment: `Get-StoredCredential : The term 'Get-StoredCredential' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Answer (score 0):

Try `cmdkey`!

```
$target = "foo"
$username = "your_username"
$password = "your_password"

cmdkey /add:$target /user:$username /pass:$password
```

For generic instead of Windows credentials, replace `/add` with `/generic`.

Tested on Windows 11 23H2.